# How to update SQL Table from two gridviews

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Merging three gridview into one.
This is the First Gridview

```
ItemCode  Itemname  NewCode   SellingPrice   PurchasePrice   MRP
   1         Soap         1         
   2         Bag          2         
   3         Cycle        3         
   4         Scissors     4         
   5         Pen          5
```

This is the Second Gridview

```
 ItemCode   NewCode
 1          55874
 2          889746210
 5          466897
```

This is the Third Gridview

```
ItemCode   SellingPrice   PurchasePrice   MRP
 1            25               20          25
 2            150              130         150
 3            7500             6500        7500
 4            20               17          17
 5            10               8           10
```

I want the first gridview to be updated with the above values and save it into the database

```
ItemCode  Itemname  NewCode   SellingPrice   PurchasePrice   MRP
1         Soap       55874         25            20          25
2         Bag        889746210     150           130         150
3         Cycle      3             7500          6500        7500   
4         Scissors   4             20            17          17    
5         Pen        466897        10            8           10
```

Comment: what you've tried to update.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    SELECT 
a.ItemCode,a.Itemname,a.NewCode,a.SellingPrice,a.PurchasePrice,a.MRP,
b.ItemCode,IFNULL(b.NewCode, a.NewCode) as NewCode,
c.ItemCode,c.SellingPrice,c.PurchasePrice,c.MRP
FROM First a
LEFT JOIN Second b
    on a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN Third c
    on a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode
```

Comment: I want to update the newcode in the first table with the newcode in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_eon",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Update tbl_All set NewCode='" + dt.Rows[i]["EanCode"].ToString() + "' where ItemCode='" + dt.Rows[i]["ItemCode"] + "'", con);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```